School boy's love story which doesn't have happy ending
I remember watching a movie where a school boy (may be around 13 year old) fall in love with a girl or similar age. Boy tries to charm her in many ways. In the middle of story they also became good friends, they are in some kind of karate classes too. Girl is good in karate and teaches the boy too. I think there is some problem in girls family too.
In the end of movie boy proposed the girl but girl rejected him by saying that they are not in the age for love and movie ended.Boys last word are like saying that he can't forget his first love in his whole life.
It's color Hollywood film  may be of 90s or 00s but i am not sure.

I think the movie you're looking for is Little Manhattan
A brief info on the movie from Rotten Tomatoes:

The bittersweet pangs of first love among sixth graders sets the stage
  for this romantic comedy. Gabe (Josh Hutcherson) is an 11-year-old boy
  living on the more exclusive side of New York City; his parents, Adam
  (Bradley Whitford) and Leslie (Cynthia Nixon), are splitting up, and
  as their marriage slowly crumbles, they've both become increasingly
  protective of their son. While most of Gabe's friends are still firmly
  in the "girls are yucky" stage, Gabe has found his head turned by
  Rosemary

